# how to get date difference in openerp?

Tags: date, odoo, difference

I want to get the number of days between two dates. How can I achieve this in openerp? I need to comapare the current date with a past date and get the number of days in between.

Comment: If this answer solve your problem then select it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here See Simple Example.

See below code.

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2013, 1, 1)
d1 = date(2013, 1, 30)
delta = d0 - d1
print delta.days
```

OpenERP follow python codes

Answer (score 0):

datetime.strptime(current_date, '%Y-%m-%d')